# Image rotation in Pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have an image and I want to transpose it by 30 degrees. Is it possible to do by using something like the following?

```
spinPicture003 = Picture003.transpose(Image.Rotate_30)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To rotate 30 degrees counter clockwise around its center use:

```
spinPicture003 = Picture003.rotate(30)
```

Answer (score 13):

If you want to keep the image size, you can use

```
spinPicture003 = Picture003.rotate(30)
```

But if you want to swap the width and height, please use

```
spinPicture003 = Picture003.rotate(30, expand=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

try using rotate() instead of transpose()