# PIL's Image.rotate() crops image

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I am trying out the Python Imaging Library, but `Image.rotate() seems to crop the image:

```
from PIL import Image 
fn='screen.png'
im = Image.open(fn)
im = im.rotate(-90)
im = im.rotate(90)
im.show()
im.save('cropped.png')
```

The original image `screen.png` is:

[image]

The cropped image `cropped.png` is:

[image]

The cropping is caused by the 1st rotation and retained in the 2nd rotation.

I am still new to Python, despite trying to become more familiar with it over the years.  Is this me doing something wrong with the PIL or is it a bug?

My Python version is:

```
Python 3.8.8 (default, Mar  4 2021, 21:24:42) 
[GCC 10.2.0] on cygwin
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30888134/image-rotation-in-pillow See here try rotate(degree, expand =1) , seems rotate keeps the image size expand swaps height with width

Comment: @pippo1980: Thanks!  It worked.  Odd name, expand, because it also shrinks any dimension needed as well.  But I can't think of a better parameter name just off the top of my head.  Did you want to post that as the answer?

Comment: @pippo1980: Thanks, I'll post it. [My googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Image.rotate%22%20crops-image%20pil) didn't reveal the cause, so it might help someone. Rotations by 90 degrees are very common, which don't change the area, so many might not realize that the official explanation for `expand` covers their requirement.

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to *pippo1980*, the solution is to specify `expand=1` when invoking `rotate()`:

```
from PIL import Image 
fn='screen.png'
im = Image.open(fn)
im = im.rotate(-90,expand=1)
im = im.rotate(90,expand=1)
im.show()
im.save('cropped.png')
```

It adjusts the "outer image" width and height to allow an *arbitrarily* rotated image to fit without cropping.  Despite the name, it also shrinks width/height where appropriate.